# Clang Static Analyzer unexpected NULL pointer warning

Tags: c, clang, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

I have the following code:

```c
int s[4096];
unsigned char o = 0;

int main(void) {
    int *n;
    return ((char *) (s + o)) == 0 ? *n : 0;
}
```

When I run the Clang Static Analyzer on that code, it warns me that I'm dereferencing `n` because `(char *) (s + o)` is a null pointer, which it's not (I can even print it and get an address that's definitely not zero).

What am I missing?

[image: Clang Analyzer screenshot]

I'm noticing that removing the `(char *)` cast makes the warning disappear.

Comment: It warns you because the condition _could_ technically evaluate to true, in which case you dereference a uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @tkausl, that makes sense, but I can't figure out in which conditions this could be true. For whatever value `o` has, this still won't be true. And this is the only codepath in the entire program, so neither `s` nor `o` can have any other values than the ones in the program. I'm also noticing that removing the `(char *)` cast makes the warning disappear.

Comment: if o is over 4096, then it is UB, then could be true

Comment: @OznOg, but `o` is an `unsigned char`, so it can only have values between `0` and `255`.

Comment: Ok, :)  I guess you expect quite a lot from the compiler :)

Comment: @OznOg, the Clang Static Analyzer did a very good job so far, this is the first time I see something that looks like a false positive. But I could be wrong and there might be something I'm simply not seeing.

Comment: Let's go over it step by step. `(char *) (s + o)`, reduces to `(char *) s` since `o == 0`. Now, `(char *)s` there's no way that can be zero, unless the OS memory allocator placed it at absolute 0 memory address, the same goes for only `s`. There's a limit with static analyzers, and also keep in mind that the *rules* for the language varies in accordance to dialect version and compiler.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz, indeed, it looks like a bug to me, especially since removing the cast makes the warning disappear, even though the condition is just as false with or without the cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was testing with the Clang Static Analyzer version 8. Version 10 no longer reports the warning.